# Growing Self-Organizing Map for mixed-type data

Tags: machine-learning, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to write code to build a growing SOM for mixed-type data. I came across a paper Growing Self-Organizing Map with cross insert for mixed-type data (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1568494612001731). It was very interesting and handled both categorical and numeric data in a unified way. However, my dataset has variables/attributes that can have multiple values (for example: attribute "interests" can have more than one value - movies, sports, and so on...). I got stuck at handling such attributes. Any inputs how to handle attributes with sets of values in a mixed-type dataset? References to material that talk about this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice when using categorical attributes in neural networks is to break the attribute in multiple binary attributes(true/false), one for each attribute value of the categorical attribute. For example if you have the attribute "interests" with values "movies", "sports", "cooking" then you will split it in three attributes, one for each value, movies with values 0/1, sports with values 0/1 and cooking with values 0/1. The only case where you could avoid such a split is when the attribute values can be ordered and thus converted to a single numerical attribute. For example if you have an attribute about quality with values poor, medium and good then you just map these values to numbers 0,1,2 or something similar. You can not do the same with attributes like "interests" because if you assign 0 to movies, 1 to sports and 2 to cooking then you consider that sports is more similar to cooking than movies which of course is wrong.
When your categorical attribute has a lot of possible values and not just three, things are getting really nasty unfortunately.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21770/encoding-categorical-features-to-numbers-for-machine-learning

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-8H0STM/index.html

google for

machine learning converting categorical to numeric

and you 'll find a lot of resource and possible optimizations to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My comment was too long to fit into a single comment, so I am breaking it into multiple comments: I was actually trying to find a more elegant approach than converting the categorical variables into binary. As you mentioned, this would explode the dimensionality of the dataset. Assuming I take this approach, there's another potential problem. I am trying to use SOM for clustering. After training the SOM and is deployed in production, What if I get a new value for an attribute that is not seen before?

Comment: That new value would be another binary column that didn't exist before when I trained the SOM. Now that I have an extra attribute in the input data object, how do I calculate distance to the map units and identify the BMU? How should I adapt the weights of BMU and its neighborhood? Should I add this new column to the prototype weights while adapting? I quoted the paper by Dr. Hsu because by converting the attributes to distance hierarchy, the dimensionality of the dataset is not changed. cntd...

Comment: Even if I come across a new value for the attribute, I can simply update the distance hierarchy and map the attribute to a point in the hierarchy. But the problem comes with a couple of my attributes having a set of values as opposed to a single value.